# Using sed to delete everything from a colon on, up until a space character

Tags: regex, sed, substitution

The first line of a text file contains hundreds of strings of the following form:

```
143362:2019111515391775
```

that are separated by spaces.  I.e.,

```
143362:2019111515391775 143760:2019111515391785 143020:2019111515391748
```

I would like to remove the portion of each string starting with the colon (i.e., delete from the colon, up until the space).

Is there an elegant way to do this with sed?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
sed 's/:[^[:blank:]]*//g'
```

This removes each colon and any number of non-blanks following it. Output for your input:

```
143362 143760 143020
```

Comment: Perfect!  Actually I realized I misphrased the question.  Could this be edited to remove the colon as well?

Comment: @ScottB. Yes, as long as there isn't any other answer.. let me update.

Comment: `[:blank:]` includes tabs as well so strictly speaking `[^ ]` represents a non-space character. Alternate less strict solution would be in GNU sed `sed 's/:\S*//g' file`